# Ошибка при установки blis на RPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Пытаюсь установить на RPi - Blis и появляется проблема

```
 Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uBB3na-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/
```

Знаком кто-нибудь с такой проблемой?
Пробовал `pip install setuptools --upgrade` и `apt-get upgrade python`.. все на новой версии

Весь лог:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install blis
Collecting blis
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/9e/84a83616cbe5daa94909da38b780e93bf566dc2113c3dc35d7b4cad52f63/blis-0.2.4.tar.gz
Collecting numpy>=1.15.0 (from blis)
Building wheels for collected packages: blis
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for blis ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpudcKICpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  ('BLIS_COMPILER?', 'None')
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
  copying blis/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
  copying blis/benchmark.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
  copying blis/about.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
  copying blis/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
  copying blis/tests/test_gemm.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
  copying blis/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
  copying blis/tests/test_dotv.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
  copying blis/py.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
  copying blis/cy.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
  copying blis/cy.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
  copying blis/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
  running build_ext
  unix
  ('py_compiler', 'gcc')
  {u'LANG': u'C.UTF-8', u'VIRTUAL_ENV': u'/home/matt/repos/wheelwright/env3.6', u'SHELL': u'/bin/bash', u'LESSCLOSE': u'/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', u'NAME': u'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', u'PS1': u'(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', u'XDG_DATA_DIRS': u'/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', u'OLDPWD': u'/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', u'TERM': u'xterm-256color', u'HOSTTYPE': u'x86_64', u'LESSOPEN': u'| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', u'SHLVL': u'1', u'PWD': u'/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', u'LOGNAME': u'matt', u'USER': u'matt', u'VAGRANT_HOME': u'/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', u'PATH': u'/home/matt/repos/wheelwright/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', u'HOME': u'/home/matt', u'LS_COLORS': u'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', u'OMP_NUM_THREADS': u'1', u'_': u'/home/matt/repos/wheelwright/env3.6/bin/python'}
  gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/generic/bli_cntx_init_generic.c -o /tmp/tmp3SL_1P/bli_cntx_init_generic.o -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
  gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/haswell/bli_cntx_init_haswell.c -o /tmp/tmp3SL_1P/bli_cntx_init_haswell.o -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
  gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/penryn/bli_cntx_init_penryn.c -o /tmp/tmp3SL_1P/bli_cntx_init_penryn.o -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
  gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/piledriver/bli_cntx_init_piledriver.c -o /tmp/tmp3SL_1P/bli_cntx_init_piledriver.o -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
  gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/sandybridge/bli_cntx_init_sandybridge.c -o /tmp/tmp3SL_1P/bli_cntx_init_sandybridge.o -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
  gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/steamroller/bli_cntx_init_steamroller.c -o /tmp/tmp3SL_1P/bli_cntx_init_steamroller.o -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
  gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/kernels/zen/1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.c -o /tmp/tmp3SL_1P/bli_amaxv_zen_int.o -O3 -mavx2 -mfma -mfpmath=sse -march=core-avx2 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
  gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-march=core-avx2’
  gcc: note: valid arguments to ‘-march=’ are: armv2 armv2a armv3 armv3m armv4 armv4t armv5 armv5e armv5t armv5te armv6 armv6-m armv6j armv6k armv6kz armv6s-m armv6t2 armv6z armv6zk armv7 armv7-a armv7-m armv7-r armv7e-m armv7ve armv8-a armv8-a+crc armv8.1-a armv8.1-a+crc iwmmxt iwmmxt2 native
  gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mavx2’
  gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfma’
  gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpmath=sse’
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py", line 266, in <module>
      'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering'
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py", line 105, in build_extensions
      objects = self.compile_objects(compiler.split('-')[0], arch, OBJ_DIR)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py", line 184, in compile_objects
      objects.append(self.build_object(env=env, **spec))
    File "/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py", line 198, in build_object
      subprocess.check_call(command, cwd=BLIS_DIR)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'gcc', '-c', u'/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/kernels/zen/1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.c', '-o', u'/tmp/tmp3SL_1P/bli_amaxv_zen_int.o', u'-O3', u'-mavx2', u'-mfma', u'-mfpmath=sse', u'-march=core-avx2', u'-fPIC', u'-std=c99', u'-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L', u'-DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6"', u'-DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY', u'-Iinclude/linux-x86_64', u'-I./frame/3/', u'-I./frame/ind/ukernels/', u'-I./frame/1m/', u'-I./frame/1f/', u'-I./frame/1/', u'-I./frame/include', '-I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64']' returned non-zero exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for blis
  Running setup.py clean for blis
Failed to build blis
Installing collected packages: numpy, blis
  Running setup.py install for blis ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uBB3na-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    ('BLIS_COMPILER?', 'None')
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
    copying blis/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
    copying blis/benchmark.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
    copying blis/about.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
    copying blis/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
    copying blis/tests/test_gemm.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
    copying blis/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
    copying blis/tests/test_dotv.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis/tests
    copying blis/py.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
    copying blis/cy.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
    copying blis/cy.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
    copying blis/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/blis
    running build_ext
    unix
    ('py_compiler', 'gcc')
    {u'LANG': u'C.UTF-8', u'VIRTUAL_ENV': u'/home/matt/repos/wheelwright/env3.6', u'SHELL': u'/bin/bash', u'LESSCLOSE': u'/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', u'NAME': u'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', u'PS1': u'(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', u'XDG_DATA_DIRS': u'/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', u'OLDPWD': u'/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', u'TERM': u'xterm-256color', u'HOSTTYPE': u'x86_64', u'LESSOPEN': u'| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', u'SHLVL': u'1', u'PWD': u'/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', u'LOGNAME': u'matt', u'USER': u'matt', u'VAGRANT_HOME': u'/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', u'PATH': u'/home/matt/repos/wheelwright/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', u'HOME': u'/home/matt', u'LS_COLORS': u'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', u'OMP_NUM_THREADS': u'1', u'_': u'/home/matt/repos/wheelwright/env3.6/bin/python'}
    gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/generic/bli_cntx_init_generic.c -o /tmp/tmpn46Nw2/bli_cntx_init_generic.o -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
    gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/haswell/bli_cntx_init_haswell.c -o /tmp/tmpn46Nw2/bli_cntx_init_haswell.o -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
    gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/penryn/bli_cntx_init_penryn.c -o /tmp/tmpn46Nw2/bli_cntx_init_penryn.o -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
    gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/piledriver/bli_cntx_init_piledriver.c -o /tmp/tmpn46Nw2/bli_cntx_init_piledriver.o -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
    gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/sandybridge/bli_cntx_init_sandybridge.c -o /tmp/tmpn46Nw2/bli_cntx_init_sandybridge.o -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
    gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/config/steamroller/bli_cntx_init_steamroller.c -o /tmp/tmpn46Nw2/bli_cntx_init_steamroller.o -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
    gcc -c /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/kernels/zen/1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.c -o /tmp/tmpn46Nw2/bli_amaxv_zen_int.o -O3 -mavx2 -mfma -mfpmath=sse -march=core-avx2 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
    gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-march=core-avx2’
    gcc: note: valid arguments to ‘-march=’ are: armv2 armv2a armv3 armv3m armv4 armv4t armv5 armv5e armv5t armv5te armv6 armv6-m armv6j armv6k armv6kz armv6s-m armv6t2 armv6z armv6zk armv7 armv7-a armv7-m armv7-r armv7e-m armv7ve armv8-a armv8-a+crc armv8.1-a armv8.1-a+crc iwmmxt iwmmxt2 native
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mavx2’
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfma’
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpmath=sse’
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py", line 266, in <module>
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering'
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 601, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py", line 105, in build_extensions
        objects = self.compile_objects(compiler.split('-')[0], arch, OBJ_DIR)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py", line 184, in compile_objects
        objects.append(self.build_object(env=env, **spec))
      File "/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py", line 198, in build_object
        subprocess.check_call(command, cwd=BLIS_DIR)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'gcc', '-c', u'/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/kernels/zen/1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.c', '-o', u'/tmp/tmpn46Nw2/bli_amaxv_zen_int.o', u'-O3', u'-mavx2', u'-mfma', u'-mfpmath=sse', u'-march=core-avx2', u'-fPIC', u'-std=c99', u'-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L', u'-DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6"', u'-DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY', u'-Iinclude/linux-x86_64', u'-I./frame/3/', u'-I./frame/ind/ukernels/', u'-I./frame/1m/', u'-I./frame/1f/', u'-I./frame/1/', u'-I./frame/include', '-I/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uBB3na-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NMmakf/blis/
```

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с правами доступа к папке /tmp

Comment: @MrMorgan через sudo такая же проблема